# Regex subsequent lookahead statements

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to understand the way regex engines handle expressions with subsequent lookahead statements. I feel I can best illustrate my question with two examples (javascript syntax) . Forgive me if my use of terminology is off.

**Example without lookahead:**

`/a(.*b)(.*c)/`

This would match an expression that contains an `a`, that at some point is followed by a `b`, which at some point is followed by a `c`. So the second atomic group `(.*c)` "applies" to the first atomic group `(.*b)`. `abc` will satisfy this expression but `acb` will not.

**Example with lookahead:**

`/a(?=.*b)(?=.*c)/` == `/a(?=.*c)(?=.*b)/`

This would match an `a`, if it is followed at some point by a `b` **and** it is also followed at some point by a `c`. So both atomic groups apply to the `a` character, regardless of order: the `a` will be matched in both `abc` and `acb`.

So I guess that regex engines treat lookahead (and lookbehind?) groups differently then they treat other groups - do they go back to the "main" expression (`a` in this case) after each time a lookahead is encountered?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Yes. Lookaheads are “zero-width assertions”; they can cause a match to fail, but don’t actually match anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Lookaround actually matches characters, but then gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match.

You can find more information [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).